# Stop html headings from making a line before and after them?

Tags: html, css

The html heading tags force a line before and after them but I was wondering if there was a way to stop it from doing that, so I can keep my heading in line with the other things I want on the same line on either side of it?

```
 <a href="foo.php">Foo</a> <h1>Bar</h1>
```

I wan't those to be on the same line but right now it would show up like

Foo

## Bar

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Headings are block-level elements by default, and blocks stack vertically, which is what you're seeing...

Comment: Honestly, though, I'd suggest avoiding dinking around with built-in block/inline settings unless there's a REALLY good reason to.  Consider using a <span> instead with your own class to format the inline text as you want.  Unlike h1, span is an inline element.

Comment: If you are going to display a heading inline, make a CSS class to do so rather than applying the inline attribute to all headings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

BoltClock is right...

which means you can do this:

```
h1 {
    display:inline;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this 'kludge' will work on all browsers but...

```
h1 {display:inline;}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/cPdwQ/

Comment: Yes, it will (barring Netscape/IE < 4 that is...) :)